# How to set JMS Message Expiry Property in WSO2 ESB 5.0

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to send a jms message on `ActiveMQ` via `WSO2 ESB`. I didn't found any property from WSO2 to set the JMS message `expiry time`. I have tried below property but didn't worked.

```
 <property name="JMS_PROD_TIME_TO_LIVE" scope="transport"
        type="STRING" value="15000"/>
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Possible value is JMS_DELIVERY_TIME
according to

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-transports/blob/master/jms/org.wso2.carbon.transport.jms/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/transport/jms/utils/JMSConstants.java

But i assume it is not yet implemented,  since IdeaIntellj highlight constant

```
public static final String JMS_DELIVERY_TIME = "JMS_DELIVERY_TIME";
```

as **not used**.

Comment: You might consider to make changes in code of JMSUtils.java in same directory  as JMSConstants.java. Not so difficult to build but have to watch out version compatibility.